# How is argv a string array when it's a char array?

Tags: c

Why doesn't `argv[0]` print the first character of the filename instead of the whole filename string?

If `argv` is a pointer to an array of chars, then shouldn't accessing it with `[n]` result with a char? If its a string (as `printf(argv[n]`) suggests) then why doesn't `argv[0][0]` get me the first char of filename (compiles but crashes when started)?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    printf(argv[0][0]);

    while (1){}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `argv` is a pointer to an array of `char` *pointers*.

Comment: The type of `main`'s second argument, conventionally named `argv`, is `char **`.  It points to the first element of an array of `char *`.  Thus, no, `argv` is *not* a pointer to an array of `char`.

Comment: A `char **` can be accessed via two indexing operators like a 2D array (`argv[0][0]`), but a 2D array is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.  You can find several questions already addressing this here on SO.

Comment: You can inspect `argv` like this `for (int i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; ++i) printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);`. Note that there is a contract that each `argv[n]` is an array of chars terminated with `'\0'` so they are *strings* in the [tag:c] sense. Also there is a contract that the last item of the array of pointers is `NULL`. If you write a program only with this code, is there a crash? Because there is certainly NOT, then why don't you post your code?

Comment: @Mawg how am i or the compiler supposed to know if ** is a pointer to a pointer or a pointer to an array of pointers, shouldnt it be ** < name > [] to indicate that its pointing to an array of pointers?

Comment: @LukaKostic The compiler doesn't care. That's why undefined behavior exists. You make a contract with yourself about that too. The notation `char *argv[]` is simply to indicate to the reader that the intended parameter is indeed an array of pointers, but in the end it's interpreted as `char **argv` anyway and the compiler really doesn't care.

Comment: "how am i [or the compiler] supposed to know if ** is a pointer to a pointer or a pointer to an array of pointers" --- that's what `argc` is for.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I think the OP is concerned about the fact that `char **` could be something like `char x = 'a'; char *xx = &x; char **xxx = &xx;` so there `xxx` is certainly not a pointer to an array of char pointers, or is it?

Comment: @LukaKostic There's a good lesson here: code speaks louder than words. Coding is all about the details, which a written out description misses. In this case, you are conceptually correct that `argv[0][0]` is the first char of the file name. The problem is that you're not printing that character correctly. Always post code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i already said argv[n][n] doesnt work and argv[0][0] compiles but crashes. Why do you need to see the code for that? its a perfect explanation of the problem not just saying "it doesnt work"

Comment: @LukaKostic `argv[0][0]` by itself doesn't crash. It's the way you used it, that's why the code is so important.

Comment: @Iharobalasimi equally valid to treat it as a pointer to an array with only one element. After all a pointer is just the address of a block of memory.

Comment: `printf(argv[0][0]);` Doesn't your compiler scream at you? Either for providing wrong type for first argument or for implicitely declaring `printf`?

Comment: Nope. Im using visual studio 2013, i get  no errors/warnings whatsoever, other than "warning C4013: 'printf' undefined; assuming extern returning int" which i dont quite understand

Comment: @LukaKostic See https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/100619-warning-c4013-errrrrr.html -- you need to add `#include <stdio.h>`. Fixing that will then lead to a warning about printf's arguments.

Comment: Well, the warning you *do* get explains why you don't get a warning about the argument type.  You have not provided a function prototype for `printf` to tell the compiler what the argument and return types are.  You would normally do that by putting a line `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of the program.

Comment: It looks like someone deleted my comment. I can't think why and invite you to tell me in chat (or here). I will repeat what I said - there are (or were) some very misguided people here claiming that the `**` notation refers to a two dimensional array - ***IT DOES NOT***. It means `a pointer to a pointer` and nothing more. That second pointer ***might*** point to an array of char, as in `argv`, but it also might not.  For instance `int **X` declares `X` as a pointer to a pointer to  an `int` - note that there is no two dimensionality involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior because you are passing a `char` to a functions that expects a pointer.

To print a single character you have these options,

- `fputc(argv[0][0], stdout);`
- `putchar(argv[0][0]); // Effectively the same as above`
- `printf("%c\n", argv[0][0]);`

you can add more of `printf()` variants.

The reason your code crashes, is because `printf(argv[0][0]);` is undefined behavior since the function will try to dereference a pointer but you passed a single character and the value of such character will be interpreted as a memory address.

You really NEED to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: How can it get confused about the address? Isnt &argv[0][0] the address and argv[0][0] the char?

Comment: @LukaKostic In the end, `char` is just an integral type, integers and pointers are interchangeable in [tag:c] but the behavior of such trade is not always defined. Moreover, if the address was one that is in the range of the memory of your program, it would still be invalid because it's not pointing to a real memory position, or is it? That would not be known beforehand and that's why this is called undefined behavior.

Comment: Clearly, pointers and integers are not *interchangable* in C, but they are inter*convertible*.  And some compilers perform such conversions even without a cast, which is an extension (though they are typically willing to emit a warning about that).

Answer (score -2):

I am using ubuntu server 14 to execute, and `gcc` compiler to compile the code and `argv[n][n]` worked for me. Take a look at this code

```
// C program to illustrate
// command line arguments
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int counter;
    printf("Program Name Is: %s",argv[0]);
    if (argc == 1)
        printf("\nNo Extra Command Line Argument Passed Other Than Program Name");
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        printf("\nChecking double array elements: %c",argv[0][0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Program Name Is: ./test
Checking double array elements: .
```

What machine are you using to compile and execute? maybe there is some other error... double check!

Comment: I needed a printf("%c",argv[0][0]) instead of just printf(argv[0][0])

Comment: Yes exactly, if you need to read a `char` from a string (array of `char`) you can do it by `%c`